# Showing lists of image to RecyclerView from internet

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, imageview, android-glide

I have a long list of images that i need to show in to recyclerView. I am using glide to show the images from my adapter.

```
Glide.with(context).load(feed.getImgLink()).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE).into(holder.myImgView);
```

The above is the code am using i set the DiskCacheStrategy to none because I'm trying to show Instagram like Feed and i didn't want to permanently cache the img on disk.

The first time i see the image there is no problem it is displayed normal but after i scroll down and back up the image reload again. I get that i haven't cache the image in to disk but there is still momery cache.

Is there any way i can solve i could use diskcache to ALL but it is taking space for just one time viewing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Glide.with(context).load(imageUrl).into(holder.myImgView);

Comment: This caches in both memory and disk.

Comment: try this .https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html